# Set icon size of JTabbedPane tab icon

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, jtabbedpane

Is there a way to easily set the size of an icon for a `JTabbedPane`tab.
The icon is the same size as the original image and therefore makes for a very ridiculous looking tab with it taking up half the screen.

How would I easily rescale this icon to be a similar size to my text "Settings" and just have it appear normally?

```
URL cogIconUrl = getClass().getResource("/images/cog.png");
ImageIcon cogImg = new ImageIcon(cogIconUrl);

JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
getContentPane().add(jtp);
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
jtp.addTab("Settings", cogImg,jp1);
```

Furthermore, how would you go about setting the font of the tab text? I assume the two are potentially related.

Comment: jtp.setFont( font ); Is how you set the font of the tab title

Comment: *"Is there a way to easily set the size of an icon for a `JTabbedPane` tab."* Resize the image. General tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize the Image:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(...);
Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(...);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon( scaled );
```

Note: the `getScaledInstance(...)` method may not be the best approach as it is slow, but for a single image you won't notice any problems.

You can read [Perils of Image.getScaledImage](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611) for more information.